# How to delete thumbnails in Twenty Fourteen theme from Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

i want to delete post thumbnails in index page. how can i do this?

[image]

*sorry about my english.*

Answer (score 0):

You should comment the following line in the following file:
wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/content.php

```
<?php /*twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail();*/ ?>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think this time it will work without changing your css

Comment: sorry, thank you for answer. where i can use the code in the content.php?

Comment: You have to add /*  */ to <?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?> line from content.php, just like in the answer. The thing is your index.php is using content.php when displaying you thumbnails. So all you have to do is comment that line from content.php

Comment: i can't found this "<?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>" cause i deleted it.

Comment: You've deleted that line and the thumbnails are still appearing?

Comment: thumbnails still appeared in index page. but single-post page doesn't appeared.

Comment: i found the answer. here : [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154909/how-to-delete-post-thumbnails-in-index-page-twenty-fourteen-theme/154917?noredirect=1#comment223211_154917) the second way works well!